# React Datepicker - Add previous and next year buttons

Tags: reactjs, react-datepicker

I am using `react-datepicker` for a project which requires the user's exact date of birth. A datepicker must be used in this instance, so dropdowns won't work here.

The issue is that there are only buttons to skip months at a time. If a user is selecting a date 20 years ago, they would have to click it 240 times, not great UX. I have not found anything in the [library docs](https://reactdatepicker.com/) about adding in this option. The closest I've found is a dropdown inside the datepicker for month and year - not as elegant.

How can I add buttons in like in the mock ups below?

Note the addition of the double arrows to skip a year at a time.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution by adapting the `customHeader` example in the docs. Still needs tweaking such as disabling buttons if out of range, designing the buttons etc. but thought it could be useful in its current state.

```js
const years = range(1990, new Date().getFullYear());
const months = [
  "January",
  "February",
  "March",
  "April",
  "May",
  "June",
  "July",
  "August",
  "September",
  "October",
  "November",
  "December"
];

/* then adding this prop to your already-configured datepicker */

renderCustomHeader={({
  date,
  changeYear,
  changeMonth,
  decreaseMonth,
  increaseMonth,
  prevMonthButtonDisabled,
  nextMonthButtonDisabled,
  prevYearButtonDisabled,
  nextYearButtonDisabled,
  increaseYear,
  decreaseYear
}) => (
  <div
    style={{
      margin: 10,
      display: "flex",
      justifyContent: "center"
    }}
  >
    <button onClick={decreaseYear} disabled={prevYearButtonDisabled}>
    {"<<"}
    </button>
    <button onClick={decreaseMonth} disabled={prevMonthButtonDisabled}>
    {"<"}
    </button>
    <p>{months[date.getMonth()]} {date.getFullYear()}</p>

    <button onClick={increaseMonth} disabled={nextMonthButtonDisabled}>
    {">"}
    </button>
    <button onClick={increaseYear} disabled={nextYearButtonDisabled}>
    {">>"}
    </button>
  </div>
)}
```